# JPackage/OpenJDK - Can't Deploy App With JNI Dependencies

Tags: java, dll, windows-10, wix, jpackage

I'm a new OpenJDK user previously using Oracle's JDKs and have only just now been able to migrate a lot of our apps past Java 8. I'm experiencing trouble with deploying standalone java applications using a Jpackage Wix installer when the apps rely on a series of native dlls.

For the sake of simplicity I am deploying an app that loads a dll which in turn loads another dependent dll.
Both dlls reside in the same folder. My java app has a third party library which loads the first dll but not the second or any further down the chain. I do not have access to this code to change what is explicitly loaded.

[image: directory structure]

I'm passing the 'nativelibs' directory at launch time in the -Djava.library.path JVM property on the command line. The first library is found with no trouble but when lib1.dll attempts to load its own dependency dll lib1-dependency.dll the jvm (OpenJDK 19) throws an exception stating that it cannot be found. The nativelibs folder is not on the system path (Windows 10 64 bit).

I've also tried flattening the nativelibs directory so that all of the .dll libraries are in the same directory as the parent executable (appinstalldir) after finding OpenJDK bug [8213772](https://bugs.openjdk.org/browse/JDK-8213772) which appears to be in the 'open' bug state for over half a decade. The behavior is the same which is shocking to me. It has always been my understanding up to this point that windows will attempt to search the current process' working directory for dependent libraries at some point during the library search order procedure but this doesn't appear to be happening.

I used Dependencies application to check for library dependency load errors but none are found and the library loads fine showing that it was able to successfully load the dependent library from the same directory as lib1.dll. My java runtime is 32 bit and the dlls are all 32 bit as well. I know this because the app works fine if I *DO* modify the user's path and put the nativelibs directory on it.

[image: DependeciesGUI.exe view of the failing dll]

How on Earth am I supposed to deploy my application without shoehorning a modification to the user's path environment variable? I do not want to modify the customer's path environment variable because what if there are other copies of the same library already on their path but they are 64 bit versions instead of the 32 bit version I am deploying? That would lead to more library load errors depending on the order of directories on their path...

Has this behavior (Windows won't search the process's working directory for a library) always been the case?
Is this truly an OpenJDK bug that hasn't been resolved yet? That seems too devastating to be the case.

The point is that what I'm trying to do is not rocket science and it seems excessively difficult to deploy a set of native libraries as a part of my deployment.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Another thing you can try is to create a .jmod file (using the `jmod` tool), which supports native libraries. Then use that jmod file to create the runtime image. In practice, `jlink` will put your native libraries in the `bin` folder of the runtime image, from where they should be able to be found.

Comment: Definitely a good idea to consider going forward as our code base becomes more 'modular' with the new JDK.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From experimenting with Java 21.0.2 on Windows 10, I found three solutions, other than the one described in [your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/78030278/6395627), that worked for me.

---

##### Include the DLLs in the Run-time Image Created by `jlink`

At least on Windows, this means putting the DLLs in the `bin` directory. There are a few ways you can do this.

1. Package the DLLs in a JMOD file via the `jmod` tool, then point `jlink` / `jpackage` at it when creating the custom run-time image.
2. Create the run-time image via `jlink`, copy the DLLs into the `bin` directory manually, then point `jpackage` at said run-time image.
3. Create the run-time image and application image in one step via `jpackage` and then copy the DLLs into the `runtime/bin` directory manually.

The last two are essentially the same thing, it just depends on when you want to copy the DLLs and whether you create the run-time image separately via `jlink` or have `jpackage` execute `jlink` for you.

The JMOD approach is the cleanest one, in my opinion. I also believe it is the least likely to break if things change about how run-time images are structured/behave. However, creating a JMOD file does require you to have a module-info descriptor. If your code is already modular then this is not much of a change (just make sure to package your code in the JMOD file along with the DLLs). Otherwise, perhaps you could create a "dummy" empty module that is only used to package the DLLs in a JMOD file.

There is no need to set the `java.library.path` system property in this case.

---

##### Include the DLLs in the Application Image Created by `jpackage` via `--input`

You are already trying to do this based on information provided in your question. However, the problem appears to be caused by the DLLs being nested under the `nativelibs` directory. Putting the DLLs directly under the `app` directory solves the problem. In other words, pass `nativelibs` to `--input`, not the parent directory of `nativelibs`.

Do not set the `java.library.path` system property in this case.

---

##### Load the Dependency First

If you have `lib1.dll` and `lib2.dll`, where the former depends on the latter, and you point to them via the `java.library.path` system property, then load `lib2.dll` *first*, followed by `lib1.dll`. Note this solution is likely to become more and more nightmarish the more complex the DLL dependency graph gets, but for just two DLLs this may be workable for you.

Comment: I'm wondering if in option 2 I have to flatten my nativelibs directory into the application directory beforehand and then pass --input. My understanding of the --input argument is that everything you pass to it ends up in the 'app' directory of the generated application image generated by jpackage. So the java jar and any native libs need to be in the same directory that is passed to the --input argument?

Comment: To clarify on option two, this works only because the app executable is injecting the /app directory on the process' Path environment variable which is good to know.

Path Entry: 'C:\Program Files (x86)\MyApplication\app'

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I didn't really look into _why_ option 2 worked, but I do remember seeing `$APPDIR` in the `java.library.path` (when not set manually). I knew (or assumed) the default value for that property on Windows was (at least partially from) the `Path`, but I didn't make the connection that `$APPDIR` was being appended to `Path`.

Comment: As for `--input`, the `jpackage` tool just takes the directory tree rooted at the specified directory and copies/mirrors it into the application directory. So, at the very least, you would need to have the DLLs as direct children of the directory you pass to `--input`. If you want a more complex layout for your JAR files, then I believe you can continue to do so as `jpackage` puts each one on the class-path with `$APPDIR\path\to\file.jar`.

Answer (score 0):

Right on schedule. Shortly after posting this question I realized that even though I flattened my nativelibs directory to put all the dlls in the same directory as my .exe file, I forgot to remove my java.library.path override which was causing the dll search order to not look in the exe working directory for some reason. This is still strange to me that the .exe process' working directory is not searched under the circumstances. Regardless, removing my -Djava.library.path JVM argument fixed the issue. The libraries MUST be in the process working directory for it to work if you don't want to touch the path environment variable.

Comment: No it doesn't work because of JDK bug 8213772 which I linked. Passing that via the --java-options will allow the app to load any library from that directory explicitly. The problem arises when one of those dlls attempts to load another dependent dll in the same directory. The first dll has no context of java.library.path and ends up just relying on Windows to load the secondary dll. If its not on the path or not in the working directory of the current process Windows will not find it. I have not tried runtime directory but I bet it has the same issue because the exe cwd is one directory above.